# excel formula looking for X formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula that will look for X in separate boxes and if it sees it then it will do a certain formula.

Basically, if N13 contains an X, then I want it to look at M3 to see if it contains an X.  If M3 contains an X as well then I want it to take the numbers (that happens to be in time) in cell I16 and subtract it from the numbers (time as well) that is in M6.  If M3 does not have an X then I want this cell to just show the time in I16.

One of the formulas tried:

`=IF((M3,N13)="X",(I16-M6),I16)` - This keeps coming back #VALUE!

Desired out come:
`I16=22:58`    `M6=11:12`    `22:58-11:12=11:46`

Comment: You want to check both M3 and N13 for X?

Comment: yes  that is correct  if N13 has an X then check M3 for an X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for X in two cells, you need to connect them with an AND function:

```
=IF(AND(M3="X",N13="X"),(I16-M6),I16)
```

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help.